# FileHelpers dynamic class generation to support [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]

Tags: filehelpers

I am using FileHelpers class for dynamic generating the class

I got the result also but when I bind to property grid its not showing the nested object. Its says class need to have this attribute
`[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]`

But the class is dynamically generated through FileHelpers so how can I provide this attribute?

I even appended the string by fails fail to create the class now dynamically.

Please advise is there a way I can add this attribute to the class created dynamically through FileHelpers.

Comment: i get this error A first chance exception of type 'FileHelpers.Dynamic.DynamicCompilationException' occurred in FileHelpers.dll

Additional information: Error Compiling Expression: 

Line 4: The type or namespace name 'TypeConverter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Line 4: The type or namespace name 'TypeConverterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: in this line   var type = ClassBuilder.ClassFromString(Code, NetLanguage.CSharp);

Comment: Can you provide a sample project ?

Comment: Have you resolved this or do you have a sample project?

Comment: pls note this attribute i added in string class that i need to convert to class object using filehelper classbuilder.    i dont think the filehelper class  builder support if the string class we used to provide has the TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter)).      there is no issues in reading a text if the class has this interface but creating a dynamic class with this interface is not supported i think .   my requiremnt was to show in the property grid for which i needed this. but  i read the output as datatable and used looped and showed in  tree to overcome this requirment